# Toggle effect don´t work

Tags: toggle

I have a problem adding toggle effect.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.contactpic').hide();
    $('.menu-item-54').click(function() {
        $('.contactpic').toggle( "slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

With this code the element (contacpic) dissapear.
If i remove the effect:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.contactpic').hide();
    $('.menu-item-54').click(function() {
        $('.contactpic').toggle(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Then, works correct.
I really appreciate any help.
Thank you.